# Python Rounding Dates

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

When I run the following code;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


Master_Revenue_Schedule = 'Master Revenue Schedule.xlsx'
df_Master_Revenue_Schedule = pd.read_excel(Master_Revenue_Schedule)
#print(df_Master_Revenue_Schedule.columns)

df_Coverage_End_Date = df_Master_Revenue_Schedule['coverage_end_date']
df_Coverage_Start_Date = df_Master_Revenue_Schedule['coverage_start_date']

Months_Calc = (df_Coverage_End_Date - df_Coverage_Start_Date)/(365.25/12)
print(Months_Calc)
```

I get the following;

```
0                        NaT
1                        NaT
2                        NaT
3                        NaT
4    11 days 23:00:51.745379
               ...
90   13 days 23:54:05.174537
91                       NaT
92   12 days 22:40:09.856262
93   15 days 23:12:41.396303
94   11 days 23:00:51.745379
df_Coverage_End_Date and df_Coverage_Start_Date both contain dates
```

I'd like to round the output. I've tried the following code but it hasn't worked.

```
Rounded_Months_Calc = round(Months_Calc,1)
print(Rounded_Months_Calc)
```

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. Please remember to use the [tag:pandas] tag if you're using Pandas.

Comment: Are you tryring to round to whole seconds?

Comment: @ScottBoston, I'm attempting to round to whole days.

Comment: you can take first 2 chars from each column, Months_Calc = Months_Calc.astype(str).str[:2]

Comment: thanks but the first value is 11.98 and I would want that value to yield a 12.